# ¿Cómo funciona este código para saber si un nodo de un árbol binario es hijo izquierdo?

Tags: python, árboles-binarios

Estoy implementando un árbol binario de búsqueda en Python. En un código en internet he encontrado una expresión para saber si un nodo es hijo izquierdo. Sin embargo, no la entiendo demasiado bien. ¿Alguien podría explicármela?

```
class TreeNode:

    def _init_(self, key, value, father = None, left = None, right = None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.father = father
        self.Lson = left
        self.Rson = right

    def hasLson(self):
        return self.Lson

    def hasRson(self):
        return self.Rson

    def isLson(self):
        return self.father and self.father.Lson == self
```

Es la ultima linea la que no entiendo, a que se refiere con self.father and self.father.Lson == self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión puede resultar un poco farragosa de leer si no estás acostumbrado a este tipo de "giros" del lenguaje (*idioms*). En concreto utiliza un par de trucos:

- [Valor de verdad de variables no booleanas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- [Evaluación de cortocircuito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_de_cortocircuito)

En el `return` python se encuentra la siguiente expresión, que será considerada como una expresión booleana por contener un `and`:

```
(self.father and self.father.Lson == self)
```

El `and` espera tanto a su izquierda como a su derecha, expresiones booleanas. La de la derecha está clara, puesto que es una igualdad. Será `True` si efectivamente son iguales o `False` si no. Pero la de la izquierda, `self.father`, no es una variable booleana.

Entonces python usa sus reglas para determinar el **valor de verdad** de una variable no booleana. En particular, si `self.father` fuese `None`, sería considerado `False`. Ese sería el caso en que el nodo actual no tenga padre. Si tiene padre, entonces `self.father` será una referencia a otro objeto, lo cual se evalúa en general como `True` (a menos que ese otro objeto tenga un método llamado `__bool__()`, en cuyo caso se llamaría a ese método para averiguar su valor de verdad, pero no es el caso aquí).

Por tanto `self.father` se interpreta en este caso como `self.father is not None`.

Por otro lado, la **evaluación de cortocircuito** implica que, tan pronto como sea posible determinar el valor de verdad de una expresión booleana compleja (que tenga varias partes unidas por `and` u `or`), se deja de evaluar.

Es decir, si tengo una expresión como `A and B and C`, para que la expresión sea `True`, tienen que ser ciertas tanto `A` como `B` como `C`. Python comenzará evaluando `A`. Si encuentra que `A` es `False`, entonces ya sabe que la expresión completa será `False`, por lo que no necesita evaluar ni `B` ni  `C`, y de hecho no los evaluará. Las expresiones `B` y `C` se han "cortocircuitado" (o quizás diríamos *puenteado*), porque `A` era `False`. Si en cambio `A` fuese `True`, seguiría evaluando `B` (y si la encuentra `False` ya no evaluará `C`), etc.

En nuestro caso si `self.father` es `None`, eso sería considerado `False`, con lo que ya no seguirá mirando si `self.father.Lson==self`. Esto nos viene muy bien, ya que si intentara evaluarlo tendríamos una excepción, por ser `self.father` igual a `None`.

Por tanto la expresión anterior equivale a esto otro, más claro quizás porque no hace uso de los trucos mencionados:

```
if self.father is not None:
   if self.father.Lson == self:
       return True
return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se hace en python una comprobación *booleana*, se consideran equivalentes a `False` *valores vacíos* como `0`, `None`, '[]', `{}` y `set()`, y como `True` todo lo demás.

Por ése motivo, `self.father and ...` es una comprobación *booleana* que comprueba que `self.father` no es `None`, o sea, que tiene un padre asignado.

La otra parte, `... and self.father.Lson == self` estaría comprobando si el padre asignado es él mismo.

Aquí habría que decir que no es del todo correcto hacer así estas comprobaciones. En python es conveniente ser **"explícitos"** y no dejar la interpretación de si es algo falso o verdadero a convenios establecidos.

Por otro lado, el operador `==` comprueba la igualdad de valores, que no es lo mismo que comprobar que la identidad de dos objetos sea la misma (sin entrar en detalles, la clase podría tener métodos propios que cambien el comportamiento de las operaciones booleanas).

Lo correcto es comprobar identidades con el operador `is` de esta forma:

```
self.father is not None and self.father.Lson is self
```

...que es mucho más literal de lo que se pretende hacer.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ha quedado muy claro ahora, y el consejo de ser explicito me ayudará bastante en el futuro, de nuevo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero verifica que el nodo actual tenga padre `self.father` luego compara que el hijo izquierdo del padre, `Lson`, sea el mismo nodo actual `self` (`self.father.Lson == self`).

Así que este método indica si el nodo actual es un nodo izquierdo.
Por ejemplo tengo dos nodos `Padre` y otro `Hijo`, luego de incializarlos y realicionarlos el método se llamaría así.
Hijo.isLson(), esto devolvería verdadero o falso según sea el caso.